# Fabric 'Answers' not getting picked up in android app

Tags: twitter-fabric, crashlytics-android

I have 3rd version of app in playstore for which `answers` and `crashlytics` are enabled and they are working fine.

I have just updated my app with 2.0.4 for which `answers` and `crashlytics` are shown in dashboard for my debug build

But for my production build i can see `crashlytics` version for 2.0.4 in the drop down but for `'Answers'` I don't see the latest apk version in drop down usually i used to see the latest build version as 'successful release' with release metrics etc..

Any help from fabric team appreciated.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I think given the format and question, SO may not be the best place for the conversation, however, sharing your app's package name would be needed for us to look into.

Comment: the package name is:.      com.krazybee.customer

Comment: I have even started a thread in twitter support but it needs a moderator approval ..

Comment: It would be great if you can provide email id so that I can share any further details if needed.....

Comment: I'm having the same issue for a different version. Did you find a solution? Or what the problem was?